# AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP'

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my Django app using the Apache2.4-Webserver. `mod_wsgi` has been installed in the project folder.
When I try to run the command `python manage.py runmodwsgi --reload-on-changes` it returns the error:

***\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py", line 158, in handle

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
```

AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP'.

How can I go about this?

Comment: That signal isn't available on Windows.

Comment: @AKX in that case how can I run the mod_wsgi?

Comment: Do you really need to use Apache? And/or Windows?

Comment: I want to make it work with Apache.